# Zipping two arrays together with index in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, zip

I have two arrays populated with integers. They are the same size (`val array1` and `val array2`).

I want to fuse them together into tuples with their index as the third element. For example if we have `val array1 = Array(5,2,6,2)` and `val array2 = Array(9,8,3,4)` then I want to get `(5,9,0),(2,8,1),(6,3,2),(2,4,3)`.

I tried doing `array1.zip(array2).zipWithIndex` but it gives `[(Int,Int),Int]` whereas I want `(Int,Int,Int)` or something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply do:

```
array1.zip(array2).zipWithIndex.map { case ((a, b), i) => (a, b, i) }
```

Comment: I can do that? That's awesome! Would it also let me convert to objects, by chance? `case ((a, b), i) => myClass(a, b, i)` ?

Comment: Absolutely! Try it :)

Answer (score 2):

With `array1.zip(array2).zipWithIndex` you are almost here.

Is This one is you want ?

```
(array1.zip(array2).zipWithIndex).map {
     case ((i, j), z) => (i, j, z)
}

res5: Array[(Int, Int, Int)] = Array((5,9,0), (2,8,1), (6,3,2), (2,4,3))
```

There is no flatten on a Tuple, but you could easyly doing it when you know the structure, like here.